# Disable DST for Calendar object

Tags: java, calendar, dst

I'm parsing a comma delimited file that has two field I need to convert to a timestamp. I get a date, and a separate field gives me minutes passed midnight... for instance:

10/15/2020, 360

now 360, for most days, would be 6am (360/60 = 6) but on DST says it could be either 5 or 7. The problem is I'm always expected to output 6am even when it's a DST day.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(schedDate);

cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(minutes));

return new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

I've tried adding the following:

```
cal.set(cal.DST_OFFSET, 0);
```

but that doesn't seem to fix the issue. I'm not sure if calendar has any built in functionality to disable DST offsets, but any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: On which time zone or offset does this depend? The one of the system or some fixed one?

Comment: Any I guess? I'm taking the system default but no matter what timezone it's running in, I'd want 360 to equal 6am every day of the year.

Comment: Then use the answer given by @ArvindKumarAvinash or my one... Both are adding the minutes to the date parsed in order to get the desired time of day.

Comment: I recommend you neither use `Calendar` nor `java.sql.Timestamp`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `LocalDateTime` which does not have to deal with time-zone (and hence DST). Note that `LocalDateTime` is part of [the modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDate.parse("10/15/2020", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/u")).atStartOfDay()
                .plusHours(6);
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-10-15T06:00
```

I also suggest you stop using the error-prone and outdated `java.util` date-time API.

If you are doing it for your Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Learn more about the modern date-time API at **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 2):

Using `java.time`, you can involve the time zone of the system or give it a fixed one.

The following code shows how you could do that:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // example input
    String date = "10/15/2020";
    long minutes = 360;
    // create a LocalDate from the String considering its format
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu"));
    // create a minimum LocalTime (the beginning of a day) and add the minutes you got
    LocalTime timeOfDay = LocalTime.MIN.plusMinutes(minutes);
    // create a zone-aware object by using the date, the time of day and the system's zone
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(localDate,
                                                    timeOfDay, 
                                                    ZoneId.systemDefault());
    // print the toString() method (implicitly)
    System.out.println(zonedDateTime);
    // or use a custom format
    System.out.println(zonedDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter
                                            .ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu HH:mm:ss")));
}
```

It outputs the following (which was run on a system with UTC+2):

```
2020-10-15T06:00+02:00[Europe/Berlin]
10/15/2020 06:00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

Now we’re at it, we can let java.time parse both fields from the CSV file (comma separated values file) and combine them:

```
        DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/u");
        DateTimeFormatter minuteOfDayFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendValue(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_DAY)
                .toFormatter();
        
        String dateString = "10/15/2020";
        String timeString = "360";
        
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateString, dateFormatter);
        LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(timeString, minuteOfDayFormatter);
        LocalDateTime dateTime = date.atTime(time);
        
        System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Output is:

> 2020-10-15T06:00

If you thought you needed a `java.sql.Timestamp` for your SQL database, you most probably don’t. You may pass the `LocalDateTime` object to your database using for example `PreparedStatement.setObject()`. If you need to control the time zone (usually a good idea), convert it to `OffsetDateTime` or `Instant` first. Search for how.

Comment: This is exactly what I did after reading both Arvind and deHaar's responses! Thanks for making me feel like I'm on the right path haha.